# Variables losing their values

Tags: php

I decided to take the advice i was given and rewrite my code in PDO format. everything works except that i can't seem to pass the values of the variables $idvar and $newvar in the UPDATE statement (last block of PHP). The variables seem to be losing their values just after POST. I've tried using hidden variables but not success. I've been at this problem for 3 weeks now. I'm sure the answer is simple but the problem is that i'm simpler. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I hope i've given enough information and formatted correctly. Thanks, Mark

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.25.0/codemirror.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.7.0/css/froala_editor.pkgd.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.7.0/css/froala_style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body id="main">



<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=my_db_name;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'my_user';
$password = 'my_password';

try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>



<?php

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblContent');
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>


<form method="POST">
<div style="text-align:center">
<select name="select1" onchange="this.form.submit()">


  <option value="null">Choose Page</option> 
  <?php
foreach($results as $row) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row['contentID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['contentpage']; ?></option>
<?php
} ?>
</select>
</div> 

</form>



<?php
if(isset($_POST['select1'])) {
$idvar = $_POST['select1'];
}
?>






<?php
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblContent WHERE contentID = :parameter');
$stmt2->bindParam(':parameter', $idvar, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt2->execute();
$results2 = $stmt2->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
foreach( $results2 as $row ){
$newvar = $row["content"];
}
?>



    <!-- Include external JS libs. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.25.0/codemirror.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.25.0/mode/xml/xml.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include Editor JS files. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/froala-editor/2.7.0/js/froala_editor.pkgd.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Initialize the editor. -->
    <script> $(function() { $('textarea').froalaEditor() }); </script>


<div class="fr-view">
<textarea>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['select1'])) {
echo $row['content'];
}
?>
</textarea>
</div>  

</div>


<script>
    initSample();
</script>


<?php
/*variable values display ok here*/
echo $idvar;
$echo $newvar;
?>


<div style="text-align:center">

<form method = "POST">
<input type="submit" name="submit1" id="button" value="Submit" />

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {

/*variable values lost by this line*/

$stmt3 = $conn->prepare('UPDATE tblContent SET content = :content WHERE contentID = :id');
$stmt3->bindParam(':content', $newvar, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt3->bindParam(':id', $idvar, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt3->execute();
}

?>
</form>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you briefly explain what it is that you are trying to achieve with this script in plain words.

Comment: This code is a horrible mix. You have to learn to separate things to keep the overview. Do not mix a form and its processing code. I know that most beginners tutorials show exactly that, but nevertheless it is plain stupid.

Comment: Sure. I have a dropdown with page names. I select one and it puts the content for that page into the Froala WYSYWIG editor. I want to edit that and update the database with the content for that page.

Comment: Your using ':content', $newvar, **PDO::PARAM_INT**

Comment: Would you mind showing me arkascha as i thought i did have everything separated

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. So obvious but i didn't notice that.

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get a syntax error on `$echo $newvar`. 3rd occurrence of $newvar on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Needs to be by reference: I added &

```
$stmt3->bindParam(':content', &$newvar, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt3->bindParam(':id', &$idvar, PDO::PARAM_INT)
```

Comment: I get an error if i put & in front As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in foo(&$a);. And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it will raise a fatal error.

Comment: This is so frustrating. I know i'm really close to getting it working even if my code structure isn't great (I'll worry about that later).

Comment: Don't suppose someone would be able to spend a little time working on this with me?